# Error while knitting rmd file with ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

```
library(ggplot2) #done this multiple times, and rmd works fine!
RIStopData<-read.csv("RIStopData.csv", sep=",")
p1 = ggplot(RIStopData, aes(x=driver_gender , y=as.numeric(stop_time)))
p1 + geom_boxplot()
```

This gives a nice boxplot when I ran the chunk in R markdown. But when I try to export this to html using `knit` feature, R gives the following error on the second line itself:

```
Error in ggplot(RIStopData, aes(x=driver_gender , y=as.numeric(stop_time))) : could
not find function "ggplot" Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle-> withCallingHandlers ->
withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted
```

This is the boxplot I get in the markdown after running the code chunk.

[image]

Comment: Please load the library i.e. `library(ggplot2)` after installing it (if not installed)

Comment: did that multiple times just to be sure. But don't think that's the problem since code chunk runs and plots the boxplot just fine.

Comment: Your error states `could
not find function "ggplot"`

Comment: yes, but that is why I checked if the library was loaded or not. and loaded it again anyway, but I still get the same error. And rmd file runs using `ggplot`, so the library is loaded.

Comment: is`library(ggplot2)` in your r chunk on your rmd?

Comment: I don't have any problem in running a reproducible example `library(ggplot2);
data(mtcars);
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear , y=mpg))
p1 + geom_boxplot()` in rmarkdown

Comment: Ughh. That's it! Thanks, @Michael Vine
Some weird reason I have a habit of loading packages through the console.

Comment: @SadanandWachche, it is something we will all forget. glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to run the markdown with the inbuilt dataset `mtcars`.  The `.rmd` file looks like below

````
---
title: "ggplot"
author: "akrun"
date: "February 13, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r ggplot}
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear) , y=mpg))
p1 + geom_boxplot()


```
````

-output

[image]